# How to remove non alphanumeric characters while keeping unicode encoded chars AND apostrophe ( \' )?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, encoding

I have a text where I want to remove all nonalphanumeric characters, but keep unicode encoded characters AND apostrophe, since it's part of words like wasn't, couldn't, French contractions, etc. I know I can do `re.sub(ur'\W', '', text, flags = re.UNICODE)` to remove all nonalphanumeric characters, but I'm not sure how to do the same to preserve the apostrophe.  Clearly `re.sub(ur'[^A-Za-z0-9\'], '',text)` doesn't work because it would get rid of unicode encoded characters. Any ideas?

Comment: What about the `\w` in the negated character class with the apostrophe?

Comment: Try `re.sub(ur"[^\w']+", "", text, flags = re.UNICODE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use character class shorthands inside character classes:

```
re.sub(ur"[^\w']+", "", text, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `re` with `re.UNICODE`, if you're working with Py2 `unicode` or Py3 `str`, the predicate functions are Unicode type aware. So you could do:

```
# Py2 (convert text to unicode if it isn't already)
if not isinstance(text, unicode):
    text = text.decode("utf-8")  # Or latin-1; whatever encoding you're implicitly assuming
u''.join(let for let in text if let == u"'" or let.isalnum())

# Py3
''.join(let for let in text if let == "'" or let.isalnum())
```

This is almost certainly slower than using `re`, but I figured I'd mention it for completeness.